# How to use libcurl in c++ to send a POST request and receive it?

Tags: c++, http, curl, libcurl

I am using the c++ libcurl to send a POST request to a webpage, but i am struggling test it. The code is use is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        const char *data = "submit = 1";

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://10.5.10.200/website/WebFrontend/backend/posttest.php");

        /* size of the POST data */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, 10L);

        /* pass in a pointer to the data - libcurl will not copy */
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

        curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }


    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 




    /* always cleanup */ 



    return 0;
}
```

This is the sample code from: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html

The outcome really confuses me. From the terminal I can see there is POST request been sent but from the web page i cannot retrieve any data. The web page is very simple php code that prints out the $_POST.
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hs2kD.jpg) and
[webpage screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yFnt.png)

Could anyone help me with this?
Why i cannot get the POST request from the web page, and how can i fix this?
Anyone can give me a better way to test the code?
Thank you guys so much!

Comment: try to add   curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

Comment: @JunheeShin Thanks, but it still does not work...

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question correctly. There are two post requests 1)in your terminal and 2)in your browser. Both calls are different. Both has different post data. hence you are seeing different $_POST values. Both are independent requests. As I said i do not understand your confusion. Do you mean When you send data through terminal(C++ executable) you want to see the data in browser?

Comment: change "submit = 1" to" submit=1"

Comment: @Ravi Yes, I thought they were the same requests. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

You have to implement a callback function that will be called by curl at every batch of data received.

See a good example here :

https://gist.github.com/alghanmi/c5d7b761b2c9ab199157#file-curl_example-cpp

Obviously you replace the simple string by whatever data type and treatment you need in the WriteCallback() function.

Copy/paste of alghanmi's example :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>


static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    ((std::string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
    return size * nmemb;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  std::string readBuffer;

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.google.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Also, you'll find a good tutorial [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html).

Comment: As I understand the documentation, the callback function is an alternative to using [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html), which OP uses.

Comment: I am learning about curl since yesterday, can you please comment why you think those two are intended for same purpose? Thanks