# Send data with libcurl to .php in c++

Tags: php, c++, libcurl

I use **libcurl** to send request to my site for fetching some info.

But I don't know how to get data from user (c++) and send that to .php file.

#### It's my c++ source which get name from user :

```
std::string userUname;
        std::cout << "[?] Enter Your Username: ";
        std::cin >> userUname;
        CURL* curl;
        CURLcode res;
        std::string readBuffer;
        curl = curl_easy_init();
        if (curl) {
            const char* testlevi = "http://example.com/a.php";
             curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, testlevi);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
            res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
            curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
            std::cout << readBuffer << std::endl;
        }
```

#### And thats my php file which gets username , and will echo:

```
<?php
$name = $_GET['name'];
if($name == "Jason"){
echo "Welcome Jason.";
}else{
echo "Username is wrong.";
}
?>
```

> I just don't know how to send `userUname` to .php file(`$_GET['name']`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use libcurl in c++ to send a POST request and receive it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317221/how-to-use-libcurl-in-c-to-send-a-post-request-and-receive-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send the userUname in the body : curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=" + userUname );

And in PHP change $_GET by $_POST OR $_REQUEST

Comment: and how can I sent 2 strings? for example , name + lastname

Comment: Try that : "name="+userUname+"&lastname="+userLastname